# Hosting multiple WCF ServiceContract implementations from a single service

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-hosting

I have a interface and for the same interface i have multiple implementation.
so i would like to ask you that how do i expose the endpoint, using one host?

**SERVICE CODE**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalculator
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Add(int num1, int num2);
}
public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    public int Add(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
public class Calculator_Fake : ICalculator
{
    public int Add(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 + num1;
    }
}
```

**HOST CODE**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCF_Service.CalService));
        host.Open();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Host Config**

```xml
<endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/CalService"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="WCF_Service.ICalculator" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you don't say it I am assuming that you want to be able to host both the fake and the real service in a single applcation. If so you can host more than one WCF service in a single application. In order to do so you will need to change the code so that it creates more than one host.

Code change

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceHost host1 = new ServiceHost(typeof(Calculator));
        host1.Open();

        ServiceHost host2 = new ServiceHost(typeof(Calculator_Fake));
        host2.Open();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Config change

```xml
<endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/CalService"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="WCF_Service.ICalculator" />

<endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/FakeCalService"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="WCF_Service.ICalculator" />
```